# I have low playback frames, even though i have good specs

Tags: animation, performance, polycount

i am creating this tutorial by Ducky 3D
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=reUQmtqptwk&t=539s&ab_channel=Ducky3D
i have a gaming laptop with the following specs:-
an RTX 3070 8gb VRAM
32 GB RAM
a 10th gen i7 with 8 cores
and all running on an nvme ssd

without texturing, in animation i get around 16 or 17 frames during playback.
setting playback sync to frame drops doesnt work
turning on simplify doesnt work
increasing memory cache limit and turning on cache disk also doesnt work.
what do i do?
Do i need a new pc?

Comment: If I had to guess, he's using a lot of geometry with no viewport simplification.  It's not unusual to get less than ideal playback in the viewport because of all the work done to display each frame in realtime.

Comment: Look into the Simplify panel in blender

Comment: @AllenSimpson, I did turn it on, and set everything to 0, it did nothing which i found odd

Comment: Are there just a lot of vertices?

Comment: @AllenSimpson 64000

Comment: @AllenSimpson im guessing thats alot ...